# dynamically decide to run dbt model

Tags: dbt

I have two model in dbt model1 and model2 I want to run model1 only in prod environment and mode2 only in stage environment how can I do that ?
I have profile.yml while where I am mentioning the environment

profile.yml :
config:
send _anonymous_usage_stats: False
Snowflake_dbt:
target: stage
outputs:
prod:
type: snowflake
env: prod
stage:
type: snowflake
env: stage

how to pick env from this file and decide if the model should run or not ?